# Disable sentry for laravel on local environment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sentry

Is there any way to disable sentry for laravel 5 on local environnement? I have removed the `SENTRY_DSN` entry from my `.env` file and *it seems to work* but I am not sure it's the right way. Should I add some check about env in `report` function? Or is there any better way? `App\Exceptions\Handler` looks like this:

```
public function report(Exception $e)
{
    if ($this->shouldReport($e)) {
        app('sentry')->captureException($e);
    }
    parent::report($e);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The suggested way to disable Sentry SDK's is by setting the SENTRY_DSN value to something falsey, so your intuition here is correct.

https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clientdev/#usage-for-end-users

Comment: Updated answer with link to our suggested API spec

Comment: Adding this started throwing 500.

Comment: link is now 404

Comment: Please update the link to
https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/laravel/

Answer (score 7):

You can check if you are in production for both the report() and render() functions.

Here is an updated `App\Exceptions\Handler` file for example.

```
public function report(Exception $e)
{
    if (app()->environment('production') && $this->shouldReport($e)) {
        app('sentry')->captureException($e);
    }

    parent::report($e);
}
```

...

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
    }

    if (app()->environment('production')) {
        return response()->view('errors.500', null, 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

This way you still have [whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops) errors showing in local and a custom 500 error page for production.

Answer (score 2):

As per the official documentation [here](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/laravel/)
You have to set SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN=null in your .env file